# Humorous mis-spelling of "spell checker"?

Tags: humor

When I back a spelling  mistake I tend to blame it on the `spear chucker`. Some get the attempt at humour, but it escapes others.

Can anyone supply a more humorous mis-spelling of "spell checker"?

Comment: There is a famous document about the deficiencies of spell checkers, which uses "spiel chequer". Check out https://boarsheadeastcheap.com/2017/10/22/hay-spiel-chequer-lessen/

Comment: Althouh amusing, this question is not a good fit for ELL Stack exchange, which is not a discussion forum.

Comment: "Spiel chequer" manages to combine both German and UK English. Nice

Comment: @Michael, how good I rephrase it to make it on topic?

Comment: It's hard to make it on-topic because it's not really a question about language and usage within the context of the forum which focuses on factual questions; you might be able to ask if other sources have used misspellings of "creative writing" humorously, although that might be considered a question on arts/literature; it might be thought of as a question on creative writing (although I don't know if the stack exchange creative writing forum would accept it, they may be more specific). Or you could discuss it on a general forum.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification (+1). What would you consider to be a general forum? I did not know that S.E had any. I was considering going to chat ...